# Adding a custom method/object to Javascript in Electron

Tags: javascript, c++, c, chromium, electron

I'm developing a custom application that might need to use a proprietary low-level library, I'm looking into the Electron platform to see if it has entry points for extensions plugins that work as if they were native JS objects.

I've tried using Electron's `<webview src="..." nodeintegration>` tag, unfortunately the tag does not support transparencies when overlayed on top of each other so direct node integration was discarded. The second option is to use iframes and have the script inside the iframe call custom JS/native methods on a 
custom object (think the `window` object).

I'm exploring the electron code base but I've just started and hoped that maybe someone more familiar with it could point me in the right direction, the ideal way would be for me to be able to create a shared library (be it linked dynamically or statically) and to be able to use the new methods on the JS code that runs as part of a web page rather than as part of Node.

Comment: Does this help http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.34.0/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/ ?

Comment: I looked into it, but  it seems native node modules are only available to decide node side of the election app; reachable through the,`main.js`script and not by the JS that is part of the Web page

Comment: I'm new to electron but it seems to me that you can use the same code (libraries) both in main process code and in renderer code

Comment: yes you can use node modules in the renderer thread unless you disable it via the flag.  Not sure why you're trying to use a tag, all examples are there and browser window has node integration on by default... the only issue i've had was making sure to compile against electron's headers/node version and not the one you installed if you are indeed building a custom low level module.